# Use array of names from Ajax call in variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 ajax calls.

First one: Produces a list of computer names. For each computer name I want to insert into the name variable in the second ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "https://server/computers/match/*",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    success: xmlParser,    
});    
var data = '';    
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("computer").each(function () {    
        data +=  $(this).find("name").text();                
    })      
}
```

Second ajax call:

```
var names = $(data).text().replace(/\s/g, "%20");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    url: "https://server/computers/name/" + names,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    success: xmlParser3

});
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. Currently, your second ajax request is happening before the first one is complete. Additionally, `data` is a string, you don't need to select it and get it's text, just use it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a callback inside your each loop function:

```
$(xml).find("computer").each(function () {
    data +=  $(this).find("name").text();
}, function() {
    var names = $(data).text().replace(/\s/g, "%20");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: "https://server/computers/name/" + names,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
        success: xmlParser3
    });
});
```